# ReplaceAll Functionality with Regular Expression In Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, replaceall

I have a string "Home   333-666-8888  Do Not Disturb" and want to extract the numbers from the string. For that I found a solution with ReplaceAll functionality in Java.

```
String ab="Home   333-666-8888  Do Not Disturb";

String bc=ab.replaceAll("[^0-9-]", "");
```

And it gives me `333-666-8888`

My concern is how does `replaceAll` functionality actually works? I used to assume that it would replace the things matching the Regular Expression with blank and return me `Home Do Not Disturb`. But It gives me `333-666-8888`. Can anyone help me in understanding how replaceAll with Regular Expression Works?

Comment: What does the `^` mean in a regular expression?

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds that your issue is down to a typo, and thus not likely to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: ^ is basically a start of string in Regular Expression

Comment: My question is something else. Can you please help. How is that expression exactly working @Dukeling

Comment: If you know what replaceAll does on a high level (replace all occurrences of the thing on the left with the thing on the right), and you read the post I linked above (which indicates that `^` is **not** the start of the string as you used it there), you should read `replaceAll("[^0-9-]", "")` as "Replace all characters that are **not** `0-9` or `-` with an empty string", which is exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks alot @Dukeling that explanation helped alot... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think that `^` means to match the start of the string, right? Well, the fact is, it *does* match the start of the string, except when placed in a character class. If it is inside a character class (`[]`), it means "anything except the characters in this character class". Therefore, your regex actually matches everything except the phone number part in your string, and replaced everything except the phone number part with empty strings!

Even if it did mean to match the start of the string, it would not have worked as you have expected. Because your string does not start with `0-9-`.

So to solve this, just remove the `^`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation @Sweeper..Helped Alot! :)

Comment: @NewGeekInTown If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Done Bro! Thanks alot..

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding about the replaceAll method is correct 
Try this :

String ab = "333-666-8888";

String bc=ab.replaceAll("[0-9-]", "");